# How to run socket.io on port 443 where apache is running?

Tags: apache, websocket, socket.io, mod-proxy-wstunnel

I need to run socket.io on port 443 (where apache run https site with Let's Encrypt)

The idea is to use a apache proxy that will redirect the traffic to the socket.io port. 
I found that solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName mysite.com
     ServerAlias www.mysite.com

     SSLEngine on
     SSLProxyEngine On
     ProxyRequests Off

     SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mysite.com.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.cer

     DocumentRoot /var/www/errorPages

     ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
     ProxyPass /503.html !

     ProxyPass / http://localhost:3999/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3999/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:3999%{REQUEST_URI} [P]

</VirtualHost>
```

I run the socket.io on port 3999
HTTPS site works fine, howevever I got http 404 errors.
I guess problem is on rewriteCond.

> websocket.js:112 WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://mysite.com/socket.io/?id=11518237&username=john failed: Error
>   during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you want to use such architecture? as far as my understanding goes both are the server itself right?.

Comment: I have the same problem - did you find a solution? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60356062/socket-io-https-proxy-config-for-apache2)

Answer (score 1):

Try mod_proxy_wstunnel

`It provides support for the tunnelling of web socket connections to a backend websockets server. The connection is automatically upgraded to a websocket connection`

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

Answer (score 0):

Use different IP addresses for the different uses. You have `<VirtualHost *:443>` which tries to use all IP addresses for the single virtual host. I think you want a `<VirtualHost pub.lic.ip.addr:443>` for Let's Encrypt and a `<VirtualHost localhost:443>` for the socket.io proxy.